# How do you differentiate a distribution function?

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions

There is much more background to this question but I suspect it won't be needed to answer the part I am questioning.

I am looking at how to scale and shift normal random variables and an example had been given where we have X is normally distributed $N({\mu},{\sigma}^2)$ and $Y=aX+b$ and I am asked to show that $Y$ is distributed $N(a{\mu}+b,a^2{\sigma}^2)$

It shows the following:  $F_Y(y)$ = $P(Y{\leq}y)$ = $P(aX+b{\leq}y)$ = $F_X({\frac{y-b}{a}})$

which I understand. However, the next step says "Differentiating for y yields the density of Y"

and they obtain $f_y(y)$ = $\frac{1}{a}$$f_X(\frac{y-b}{b})$

I do not understand how to differetiate distribution functions, I can see that some standard rules of differentiation have applied here but I am uncertain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate a distribution function the same way you differentiate any function. You probably know that a random variable's probability density function is the derivative of its cumulative distribution function. Therefore

$f_Y(y) = \cfrac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) = \cfrac d{dy}F_X\left(\cfrac{y-b}a\right)$

By chain rule,

$\cfrac d{dy}F_X\left(\cfrac{y-b}a \right) = f_X\left(\cfrac{y-b} a \right) \cdot \cfrac{d}{dy} \cfrac{y-b}a = \cfrac 1a f_X\left( \cfrac{y-b} a \right)$

When you plug this into the known pdf of $X$ you will be able to see that $Y$ is normally distributed. The easiest way to prove its expectation and variance is to use what you know about $\mathsf{E}[aX+b]$ and $Var(aX+b)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $ g: R \rightarrow  R$ is increasing and differentiable (thus invertible), then

$ f_{g(X)} (y) = f_{X}[g^{-1}(y)]\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y).$

**Proof**

Consider the distribution function:

$F_{g(X)}(y) = P(g(X)\leq y) = P(X \leq g^{-1}(y)) = F_{X}(g^{-1}(y)).$

Differentiate with respect to $ y $ to get resultat.

A similar result holds if $ g $ is decreasing. This same argument as above gives

$ f_{g(X)} (y) = -f_{X}[g^{-1}(y)]\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y).$